# How can you identify all permissions granted to an application using Microsoft Graph & C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I've searched the internet and SO and have only found one answer to the same question; but it was specific to Android programming and I didn't see a clear way to port it to C#.

I would like to know how this could be done using C#. Code snippets or an actual example would be great.

Basically, I have a registered Application in Azure and need to know how to acquire all the permissions the application has been granted via code.

That would be inclusive of both Delegated and Application specific permissions.

How would one go about doing that? A linked reference would be fine as well, but I wasn't able to find anything. There are REST API's listed to find permissions for groups, users, folders and etc. Nothing I've found shows API's for listing Application permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supported to retrieve application permissions via [`GET /applications/{id}` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta) **but** only under the `/beta` version at the moment

> APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change.
>   Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

**Details**

Endpoint `GET /applications/{id}/requiredResourceAccess` returns [`RequiredResourceAccess` collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/requiredresourceaccess?view=graph-rest-beta) which:

> resources that this application requires access to and the set of
>   OAuth permission scopes and application roles that it needs under each
>   of those resources

C# example (via [`msgraph-sdk-dotnet` library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet))

```
var requestUrl = $"{graphClient.BaseUrl}/applications/{id}/requiredResourceAccess";
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
await graphClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(message);
var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(message);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var resourceAccesses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RequiredResourceAccess>>(JObject.Parse(content)["value"].ToString());
```

where

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class RequiredResourceAccess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier for the resource that the application requires access to.
    /// This should be equal to the appId declared on the target resource application
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("resourceAppId")]
    public string ResourceAppId { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// The list of OAuth2.0 permission scopes and app roles that the application requires from the specified resource.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("resourceAccess")]
    public List<ResourceAccess> ResourceAccess { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ResourceAccess
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The unique identifier for one of the oAuth2Permission or appRole instances that the resource application exposes.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies whether the id property references an oAuth2Permission or an appRole. Possible values are "scope" or "role".
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Since the provided endpoint returns the result in the following format:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#applications('e7de2f36-a0c1-4573-91bd-c854eaff0852')/requiredResourceAccess",
    "value": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "1ec239c2-d7c9-4623-a91a-a9775856bb36",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                //... 
            ]
        },
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "d13f72ca-a275-4b96-b789-48ebcc4da984",
                    "type": "Role"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

you might want to get *the details of resource that the application requires access to and permission scopes* (e.g. API and permission name which is getting displayed in Azure Portal API permissions page)

[image]

For that matter [`GET /servicePrincipals` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta) could be utilized.

Example:

For resource with id `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` the request `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?filter=appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'` returns the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#servicePrincipals",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "414583a1-9d42-4309-aa10-3bf73ff7f95e",
            "appDisplayName": "Microsoft Graph",
            "appId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
             //...
            "publishedPermissionScopes": [
                 {
                    "adminConsentDescription": "Allows the app to create, read, update, and delete events in user calendars. ",
                    "adminConsentDisplayName": "Have full access to user calendars ",
                    "id": "1ec239c2-d7c9-4623-a91a-a9775856bb36",
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "type": "User",
                    "userConsentDescription": "Allows the app to read, update, create and delete events in your calendars. ",
                    "userConsentDisplayName": "Have full access to your calendars  ",
                    "value": "Calendars.ReadWrite"
                },
                //...
             ]
          }
     ]
}
```

which contains the details about resource (e.g. `appDisplayName:Microsoft Graph`) and permission scopes (e.g. `value:Calendars.ReadWrite`)

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.